# Rails 3 Routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an issue where I have an admin subdomain setup in the routes like so:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'admin' do
scope :module => "admin" do

  match 'articles/:id/', :to => 'articles#show'

  resources :articles, :events do
    collection do
      post :update_attribute_on_the_spot
    end
  end

  root :to => "dashboard#index"

end
end
```

Then after that on articles for the main site I have:

```
  resources :articles, :events, :george
  match '/:year/:month/:day/:slug', :to => 'articles#show', :as => "article", :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/, :day => /\d{1,2}/ }
  match '/event/:year/:month/:day/:slug', :to => 'events#show', :as => "event", :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/, :day => /\d{1,2}/ }
```

I am wondering how I make sure the main site routes are not used when the admin subdomain routes are in effect, as of now when going to the admin section articles show is mapped to the main site route and therefore the admin routes will not function unless that route is removed.

If anyone can show me the best way around this issue it would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize declaring something with :as would overwrite any other route so simply:

```
match '/:year/:month/:day/:slug', :to => 'articles#show', :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/, :day => /\d{1,2}/ }
```

Fixed everything!